# How can I re-enable the "Edit Links" button after selecting "Unlink"?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I used the "Unlink" button because I didn't want my power query to pull in new data (through an accidental refresh, for example).

But now I want to re-enable the link between my power query and the data source.

Yet the "Edit Links" button is greyed out.

When I navigate to the "Data Source Settings" in the power query editor, I can see my data source is still listed.

And actually, I was able to add a different data source and I can manually refresh this data.

But, the "Edit Links" button is still greyed out.

[image: Edit Links button is greyed out]

How do I get the "Edit Links" functionality back?

EDIT: This issue persists when I load the query data to a new table in the workbook -- my data is not refreshing, and the "Edit Links" button is greyed out for all tables and sheets in the workbook.

Comment: Once unlinked, you can't then link a query to the table which remained after unlinking. And the Edit Links button is actually not relevant here.

Comment: Is it possible to move the query to a new workbook, or at least copy the steps or something, so that I can salvage the query and not start my work over? I need to re-establish this link somehow.

Comment: Why can't you just load the query to a new table? Your query is in no danger of being lost - once you unlink it from its source table, it simply changes its load status to 'Connection Only', which you can simply amend back to 'Table' by right-clicking on the query and selecting 'Load To'.

Comment: When I unlinked it, it didn't change to "Connection Only"... which is why I'm not sure how to proceed. I actually also changed the data source to a different table, and the "Edit Links" button is still greyed out (and it's greyed out for all my queries, not just the one I unlinked), so I don't understand why tie "Edit Links" button is still greyed out if I changed the data source.

Comment: and btw when I select "Load To" a different table, this changes nothing

Comment: Edit links has nothing to do with Power Query. It is for things like when you paste data from another workbook and want to keep it linked to the source.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought unlinking the data would prevent my power query from retrieving data from the data source? or is that totally wrong?

Comment: Unlinking only means that the query no longer refreshes the table to which you originally loaded the query. The query and its sources remain unchanged and active.

Comment: You seem to think that the Unlink option removes the data source from the query. But that's not the case. The only way to change the data source for a query is to do so within the query itself. The Unlink feature within the Table options has nothing whatsoever to do with the query's data source.

Comment: @JosWoolley so "Unlinking only means that the query no longer refreshes the table to which you originally loaded the query" was exactly what I expected would happen. My question remains, how do I undo this? Because even when I load the query to a new table, the same issue remains (my data is not refreshing).